# set TintColor for UINavigationBar globally in iPad application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

What would be the best approach for this?  Seems so redundant to have to set it each and every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [page](http://surgeworksmobile.com/iphone/uinavigationbar-tint-color-issue-on-ipad) shows you should be able to just subclass `UINavigationBar`. I've done this for iPhone apps for a while now. If you're using Interface Builder, remember to update class references to `UINavigationBar` with your custom subclass name, say `CustomNavigationBar`.

Hope it helps.